# Azure ML studio web service serialization

Tags: python, web-services, azure-machine-learning-service

I’m trying to set up a web service from a Python notebook in azureml and I want it to return a dictionary of {string: float}. The floats serialize just fine, but the strings do not.

This is the function I'm using:

```
def demoservice(N, Vy, My):
    X = scaler.fit_transform([N, Vy, My])
    res = clf.predict(X)
    a = [ {'diam': x[0], 'radius': x[1], 'thickness': x[2]} for x in res]
    return a
```

the call:

```
demoservice("140", "100", "0")
```

correctly returns:

```
[{'diam': 16.0, 'radius': 2.0, 'thickness': 5.0}]
```

but the web call returns this json response:

```
{"Results":{"output1":{"type":"table","value":{"Values":[["{\"type\": \"list\", \"value\": [{\"type\": \"dict\", \"value\": [[{\"type\": \"bytes\", \"value\": \"ZGlhbQ==\"}, {\"type\": \"float\", \"value\": \"16.0\"}], [{\"type\": \"bytes\", \"value\": \"cmFkaXVz\"}, {\"type\": \"float\", \"value\": \"2.0\"}], [{\"type\": \"bytes\", \"value\": \"dGhpY2tuZXNz\"}, {\"type\": \"float\", \"value\": \"5.0\"}]]}]}"]]}},"output2":{"type":"table","value":{"Values":[["data:text/plain,Execution OK\r\n",null]]}}}}
```

As you can see, in the response the dictionary's keys are not being serialized correctly. For example:

```
{\"type\": \"bytes\", \"value\": \"cmFkaXVz\"}
```

here I have `cmFkaXVz` instead of a readable value.

Comment: It returns that way because it is responding with the literal quotation characters. The work-around I take is to use `string.replace('\\','')` on the json response.

Comment: @Wes I don't think that's what he's referring to. Rather, it's the fact that strings do not have correct values.

Comment: @alexlomba87 that seems obvious now that you pointed it out. In response to that, I've had issues in the past with Azure web services serializing string responses as base64 byte strings. In the case of `{\"type\": \"bytes\", \"value\": \"cmFkaXVz\"}`, I was able to reuse a parsing line from one of my logic apps. By setting `byte_string = '\"cmFkaXVz\"'`, I can get the value by using  `base64.b64decode(byte_string.replace('\\\"',''))`